# Html Helper HiddenFor Name broken, Id missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorgenerator

I am using `RazorGenerator` to embed a view into a shared DLL. I have a `HiddenFor` that is generating an invalid `name` attribute and a missing `id` attribute.

I have a view model:

```
public class InsuredPartiesViewModel
{
    public List<OrganisationViewModel> OrganisationWithBranches { get; set; }
    ...

public class OrganisationViewModel : IInsuredPartyViewModel
{
    public bool CanQueryIVTRForBranches { get; set; }
    ...
```

In the Razor view I am using a `@helper` to iterate through:

```
@helper RenderHiddenFieldsForInsuredParty(int insuredPartyIndex, bool branchesAreVisible)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.OrganisationWithBranches[insuredPartyIndex].CanQueryIVTRForBranches)
    ...
```

The output is:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The HasQueryIVTRForBranches field is required." name="&lt;>4__this.Model.OrganisationWithBranches[0].HasQueryIVTRForBranches" type="hidden" value="False" />
```

The expected output is (I can see this from an older code branch):

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The HasQueryIVTRForBranches field is required." name="&lt;>4__this.Model.OrganisationWithBranches[0].HasQueryIVTRForBranches" type="hidden" value="False" />
```

The `id` attribute is missing and the `name` attribute of `&lt;>4__this.Model.OrganisationWithBranches[0].HasQueryIVTRForBranches` looks like Razor's parser is getting stuck.

**Have you seen this before? How do I debug the Razor output?**

Identical behaviour in VS2013 and VS2015, ASP.NET MVC 5. The data is correct going into the View.

### Update

The helper method `NameFor` also produces the error result.

```
@Html.NameFor(x => Model.OrganisationWithBranches[insuredPartyIndex].CanQueryIVTRForBranches)
```